# WP login redirect to referral link

Tags: wordpress

Current user journey
Post required membership - click login button - login page - my account page

I would like to have this user journey
Post required membership - click login button - login page - Post that required login in the first place.

I have tried using wp redirect but it's not working. I am totally open to suggestion of ways to achieve this

Comment: Have you tried wp_redirect() function?

Comment: see this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url

Comment: yes, I tried this, but just didn't work. maybe because I now have a login page that's on front-end ??